# return none, if nothing's between this two list in common

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):
result = []
seen = set()
for element in list1:
    if element in list2 and element not in seen:
        result.append(element)
        seen.add(element)
result.sort()
return result
```

print (common_elements([3, 12, 9, 15], [2, -9, 8, 8, 5, -13]))

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. It:

> return none, if nothing's between this two list in common

```
def common_elements(list1,list2):
   if [e for e in list1 if e in list2]==[]:
       return None
```

But if you want it more simplified:

```
def common_elements(list1,list2):
   pass
```

Comment: What if there are some common elements?

Answer (score 2):

You are already using a set, so why not take advantage of that:

```
>>> def common_elements(a, b):
...     return list(set(a).intersection(b))
...
>>> common_elements([3,12,9,15],[2,-9,8,8,5,-13])
[]
>>> common_elements([3,12,9,15],[2,-9,8,8,5,-13,9])
[9]
```

If you really want to return None:

```
>>> def common_elements(a, b):
...    return list(set(a).intersection(b)) or None
...
>>> common_elements([3,12,9,15],[2,-9,8,8,5,-13])
>>> common_elements([3,12,9,15],[2,-9,8,8,5,-13,9])
[9]
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, late by 4 mins :)

Comment: Sorting was a requirement? You should clarify that =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution with `filter` operation:

```
def common_elements(list1,list2):
   result = list(filter(lambda x: x in list2, list1))
   return result or None
```

Comment: You can simply `return result or None`

Comment: You are correct, that's much more concise, although I do have a hard time digesting the semantics of Empty or None == None. But that's just me :)

Comment: Only `None` is equivalent to `None`; and empty list is a "Falsey" value; so in effect it becomes False or None. Since False isn't True, the second `or` condition is returned. In effect it is saying if the list is empty, return None, otherwise return the list (any container where length > 0 is a "True").

Comment: I understand the logic behind it. But in a world where an empty list is considered falsity, should None really be analogous to true?

Comment: `None` is in no way analogous to `True`, so your question is badly preconditioned.

Comment: Then why does `False or None` return `None`? I may be missing something here but from the looks of it `None` does behave like something truthful